# How can I display a different value using this code snippet?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a calculator where a user can press a number value and than the exact value being displayed on an input (type="text") element each time its pressed. My JS code works but the only number being displayed is 1 no matter what number button is pressed. As a side note, I am using an event handler that passes an argument of the global variables I have declared at very top (i.e. one, two...) to activate the JS code.

After the first switch case I have attempted to increment the (num) and then set it equal to the (#displayField), but that just prevented the code from running. I have even attempted to use an (if...else) conditional statement but the results were identical.

```
//Calculator buttons

let one = document.querySelector("#one").value;
let two = document.querySelector("#two").value;
let three = document.querySelector("#three").value;
let four = document.querySelector("#four").value;
let five = document.querySelector("#five").value;
let six = document.querySelector("#six").value;
let seven = document.querySelector("#seven").value;
let eight = document.querySelector("#eight").value;
let nine = document.querySelector("#nine").value;

//Input Element
//#displayField is the input(type="text") field.
/*pass the arguments (variables one, two...) from the HTML document event handlers.*/

function inputs(num) {
  switch(num) {
    case one:
      document.querySelector("#displayField").value = 1;
      break;   
    case two:
      document.querySelector("#displayField").value = 2;
      break;
    case three:
      document.querySelector("#displayField").value = 3;
      break;
  }
}
```

I want case two and those after to display the appropriate values assigned instead of 1.

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear about what you want

Comment: How is the function `inputs` getting called?

Comment: AndreFeijo - I call the function (inputs) from my HTML document using an event handler.

Comment: joyBlanks - I am trying to get the numbers 2, 3, 4 etc to be displayed on the #displayField. But every time I call the function and press any button on the calculator the only number that is being displayed is one.